# Single Build with Multiple Artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, artifacts

I'm a little confused on the Azure Pipeline steps.  My solutions has many projects and one *UI* project that contains both an ASP.Net-Core WebApi/MVC with Angular.

the `Build Solution` builds similar to the

```
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
      /p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
      /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
      /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
      /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

The default `Publish Artifact` is:

```
steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

I'd like to do something with 2 artifacts (this doesn't work):

```
steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: webapi'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\MVCProject\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\netcorapp2.2'
    ArtifactName: webapi
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: angular'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\MVCProject\clientapp\dist'
    ArtifactName: angular
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

What am I missing / What the *right/better* way to do this.
(moving angular out of the project does not solve this problem, and we aren't ready for that yet)

Comment: Did you solve this? I've ran into a similar decision. FWIW I went the other way, that is: a single artifact with multiple packages.

I ran into all sorts of issues with this as it seems to confuse the release pipeline and it's any persons' guess as to which application is deployed where...

Comment: @StePammenter Yes I did (finally).  Answer incoming.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. As it turned out for me, my fault was in copying the same Azure function settings, not with the pipeline itself!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my YAML for multiple artifacts from a single build.

```
pool:
  name: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio
  - vstest
  - npm

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution WebApi'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArchitecture: x64

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: WebApi'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'dotnet-webapi'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: 'Delete build.artifactstagingdirectory for Angular'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    Contents: '**'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
    workingDir: project/ClientApp
    verbose: false

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm run prod-build'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: project/ClientApp
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run prod-build'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm run dev-build'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: project/ClientApp
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run prod-dev'
  enabled: false

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Angular/Dist to build.artifactstagingdirectory'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: project/ClientApp/dist/ClientApp
    Contents: |
     **
     !config.json
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Angular'
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: angular
```

Comment: In a release pipeline, how would you specify which Build Artifact to use?

Comment: @Dbloom Both artifacts are available when you select a folder/archive/package in the  release pipeline task.  So I just select the one I need for the correct release task.

Answer (score 7):

I managed to get Erik's approach working which is great.

I then wondered if I could simplify it so instead of deleting the content how about put each artifact in a sub folder of the **$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)** So by just appending /Api or /App I could create specific publish folders that I could then push onto the azure pipeline.

You can then have as many artifacts as you need :)

The important parts to take from this are that **publishWebProjects** needs to be set to **false** or it defaults to true and then ignores the projects line below, and the **output** path puts the content in a sub folder.

```
 # This need to be false in order for the specific project to be published
 publishWebProjects: False
 projects: '**/DevOpsApp.csproj'
 arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/App'
```

and **pathtoPublish** need to then point to the sub folder

```
pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/App'
```

Full example file below

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'
    versionNumber: 1.0.0

name: $(versionNumber)-wip-$(Rev:r)

#----------------------------------------------------------
# Web API Build and Artifact
#----------------------------------------------------------

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/DevOpsApi.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*Tests.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    testRunTitle: 'Unit Tests'

# Publish the artifact
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    # This need to be false in order for the specific project to be published
    publishWebProjects: False
    projects: '**/DevOpsApi.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Api'
    zipAfterPublish: True

# Publish the artifact for the pipelines to use
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publishing WebAPI Artifact'
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Api' 
    artifactName: 'TestWebApi-Wip'

#----------------------------------------------------------
# Web APP Build and Artifact
#----------------------------------------------------------

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/DevOpsApp.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

# Publish the artifact
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    # This need to be false in order for the specific project to be published
    publishWebProjects: False
    projects: '**/DevOpsApp.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/App'
    zipAfterPublish: True

# Publish the artifact for the pipelines to use
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publishing WebAPP Artifact'
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/App' 
    artifactName: 'TestWebApp-Wip'
```

Answer (score 3):

Can I suggest building and publishing the artefacts in [separate jobs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)? That would mean that each job is simpler (no need to specify an artefact subfolder), and might give you some speed-up by running them in parallel. Something like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  - job: web_api
    displayName: Web API Build and Artifact
    steps:
      - checkout: self

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'Build'
        inputs:
          command: 'build'
          projects: '**/DevOpsApi.csproj'
          arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
      
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: 'test'
          projects: '**/*Tests.csproj'
          arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
          testRunTitle: 'Unit Tests'
      
      # Publish the artifact
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: 'publish'
          # This need to be false in order for the specific project to be published
          publishWebProjects: False
          projects: '**/DevOpsApi.csproj'
          arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          zipAfterPublish: True
      
      # Publish the artifact for the pipelines to use
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: 'Publishing WebAPI Artifact'
        inputs:
          pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
          artifactName: 'TestWebApi-Wip'
  
  - job: web_app
    displayName: Web APP Build and Artifact
    dependsOn: []
    steps:
      - checkout: self

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        displayName: 'Build'
        inputs:
          command: 'build'
          projects: '**/DevOpsApp.csproj'
          arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
      
      # Publish the artifact
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: 'publish'
          # This need to be false in order for the specific project to be published
          publishWebProjects: False
          projects: '**/DevOpsApp.csproj'
          arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
          zipAfterPublish: True
      
      # Publish the artifact for the pipelines to use
      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        displayName: 'Publishing WebAPP Artifact'
        inputs:
          pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
          artifactName: 'TestWebApp-Wip'
```

Also: if each job tends to have a similar set of tasks, you could refactor them into a [template](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) to keep the pipeline code terser.

Comment: I know that name Vince Bowdren, think I've worked with you in the past, :) Cheers